# How to show $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]_2$ is a UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

> I would like to know how to show $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]_2$ is a UFD.

I am actually given hints that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ has class group $\mathbb{Z}/2$ and
that $(1 + \sqrt{-5},2)$ is not principal, but I can't quite figure how to use these hints.
Thank you!

Comment: What is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]_{\color{red}2}$?

Comment: The ring localized at $2 \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. Thanks!

Comment: Still not enough information (for me, anyway). Do you mean the localization where now $2$ is a unit?

Comment: Yes, I meant here the localization where I take my multiplicative  set to be $\{1,2,4,8,16,...\}$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nagata's theorem says that if you have a Krull domain (in particular, a Dedekind domain) $R$ and $S\subset R$ a multiplicative set, then $\operatorname{Cl}(R)\to\operatorname{Cl}(S^{-1}R)$ is surjective and its kernel is generated by the classes of prime ideals that meet $S$.
In our case the only prime that meets $S$ is $P=(1 + \sqrt{-5},2)$, so the kernel is generated by the class of $P$. Moreover, $P^2=(2)$, so the class of $P$ has order two. This shows that the class of $P$ not only generates the kernel, but $\operatorname{Cl}(\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}])$ as well. In particular, in our case the map is trivial, so its image is zero.

Comment: For those wanting a reference: this theorem of Nagata can be found in section 7 of Fossum's book, The Divisor Class Group of a Krull Domain.

Answer (score 4):

It’s been a while, but I think you may be able to use this strategy: Your two rings are $R=\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ and $R'=\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}][1/2]$—a notation that I find less ambiguous. I think you should be able to show that the class group of $R$ maps onto that of $R'$, and that certainly the ideal you mentioned, representing a nonzero element of the class group of $R$, definitely becomes trivial in that of $R'$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I ended up accepting the one just because the explanation was little more detailed. Nevertheless, this was very helpful also. Thanks!