# Standard argument for making the class group of a number field trivial

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field and let $R=\mathcal{O}_K$ be its ring of integers. Let $a_1, \ldots, a_h$ be ideals of $R$ generating the class group $Cl(K)$. Let $S$ denote the set of valuations corresponding to prime ideals dividing $a_1\cdots a_h$. Let 
$$R_S = \{a \in K \mid v(a)\geq 0,\ v \text{ non-Archimedean valuation on } K, \  v \notin S \}$$
Silverman (p.213 Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves) claims that $R_S$ has trivial class group. I’m sure this is a standard and simple fact, but I’m having trouble proving it.

We have an inclusion $R \to R_S$ and a map $Cl(R) \to Cl(R_S)$. Let $I$ be an ideal of $R_S$, we want to show it is principal. We have $I \cap R \equiv \prod a_i^{e_i}$ in the class group so there exists principal ideal $P,P’$ of $R$ such that 
$$P(I\cap R) = P’ \prod a_i^{e_i}$$
$$P(I\cap R)R_S = P’ \prod a_i^{e_i}R_S$$

Got stuck. Somehow the $a_iR_S$ become principal in $R_S$. I know 
$$R=\bigcap\limits_\mathfrak{p} R_\mathfrak{p}$$
$$R_S=\bigcap\limits_{\mathfrak{p} \notin S} R_\mathfrak{p}$$
Where $\mathfrak{p}$ ranges over all maximal ideals of $R$

Comment: @Watson thank you so much for the detailed answer! At first it was confusing the line J=xa_i (what is J, why only one a_i) but I figured out what you meant and basically the idea is the a_i become principal

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1144386 (recall that a Dedekind is a PID iff it is a UFD).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
\newcommand{\O}{\mathcal O}
\newcommand{\Cl}{\mathrm{Cl}}
\newcommand{\p}{\mathfrak{p}}
$
Let $K$ be a number field, and $a_1, ..., a_h$ be ideals of $\O_K$ which are representatives of the ideal classes of $\Cl(\O_K)$ (in particular, $h$ is the class number of $K$).
Let $S$ be a finite set of places of $\O_K$, containing all the prime factors of all $a_i$, as well as all infinite places.

**Claim :** The ring $\O_{K, S}$ is a principal ideal domain.

**Proof :**

By [proposition 23.2](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf#page=305) b) and d), the ring $\O_{K, S}$ is a Dedekind domain, and every ideal of $\O_{K,S}$ is an extended ideal, i.e. of the form $J\O_{K,S}$ for some ideal $J \subset \O_K$.

By definition of the ideals $a_i$, there is an element $x \in K^{\times}$ and an index $i$ such that
$$J = x a_i.$$
The ideal $a_i^h = y \O_K$ is principal (where $y \in \O_K$), since the class group is annihilated by $h$. One sees that $y \in a_i \cap \O_{K,S}^{\times}$ (because $a_i^h \subset a_i$ and the only primes dividing $y$ are in $S$), which implies that
$a_i \O_{K,S} = (1)$
and finally
$$J \O_{K,S} = x \O_{K,S} \subset \O_{K,S}$$
is a principal ideal, as claimed.

---

Remarks:

**1)**
Instead of using proposition 23.2 above, one can first show that $\O_{K,S}$ is equal to a localization $\Sigma^{-1}\O_K$, namely for the multiplicative set $\Sigma$ of elements $a \in \O_K \setminus \{0\}$ such that the only prime factors of $a \O_K$ belong to $S$, that is
$$\Sigma = \bigcap_{\p \not \in S} (\O_K \setminus \p) = \O_K \setminus \bigcup_{\p \not\in S} \p.$$
(There seems to be a typo on page 41 of [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=GssiDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA41). The "multiplicative" set they are considering doesn't even contain $1$).

Notice that we want to show the equality
$$\left( \bigcap_{\p \not \in S} (\O_K \setminus \p)  \right)^{-1} \O_K = \bigcap_{\p \not \in S} ((\O_K \setminus \p)^{-1} \O_K),$$
which is *not* obvious.

$$ $$
A) We clearly have $\Sigma^{-1} \O_K \subseteq \O_{K,S}$. The reverse inclusion is not obvious: it uses the fact that the class group of $\O_K$ is torsion (because finite) — see [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/8410Krumm--Dedekinddomains.pdf). In fact the argument is similar as above: pick $x \in \O_{K,S}$. For every $\p \in S$ such that $v_{\p}(x) < 0$, write $\p^h = b_{\p} \O_K$ as an principal ideal. Then
$b := \prod\limits_{v_{\p}(x) < 0} b_{\p}^{-v_{\p}(x)}$ is an element of $\O_K$ only divisible by primes in $S$, so that $b \in \Sigma$.
Finally, $bx \in \O_K$, so we conclude that $x \in \Sigma^{-1} \O_K$ as desired.

[Here is a wrong proof that  $\O_{K,S} \subset \Sigma^{-1} \O_K$ : if $x \in \O_{K,S}$ is non-zero, then fix $b_p \in p^{-v_p(x)}$ for every prime $p \in S$ such that $v_p(x)<0$. Then $b = \prod_p b_p \in \Sigma$ and $xb \in \O_K$, so that $x \in  \Sigma^{-1} \O_K$. The problem is that $b$ may have prime factors outside $\{ \p \mid a_i \}$, so that $b \in \Sigma$ is not true].

See also here, or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533951/) about relation between overrings and localizations. Moreover, remark 2.1 [here](http://iml.univ-mrs.fr/editions/biblio/files/lachaud/2000b.pdf#page=2) might be of interest (but there is no proof there).
Finally, more general statements are given in [theorem 2 here](https://books.google.com/books?id=jylzc3yfYUoC&pg=PA438), mostly proven in Fossum, *The Divisor Class Group of a Krull Domain*.

$$ $$
B) Once you know that $\O_{K,S} \cong \Sigma^{-1}\O_K$, you can apply proposition 3.11.1) in Atiyah, MacDonald, *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*, to conclude that any ideal of $\O_{K,S}$ is indeed an extended ideal $J \O_{K,S}$, where $J$ is an ideal of $\O_K$. (Moreover, any localization of a Dedekind domain is still Dedekind, see [here](https://planetmath.org/proofoflocalizationsofdedekinddomainsarededekind)).

$$ $$
C) You can also look at [prop. 4.19 here](http://people.math.gatech.edu/%7Embaker/pdf/ANTBook.pdf#page=99), but notice that they *define* $\O_{K,S}$ as a localization.

$$ $$
**2)** Here we are considering the multiplicative set
$\Sigma = \O_K \setminus \bigcup\limits_{\p \in \mathrm{Spec}(\O_K) \setminus S} \p.$
If instead you consider $\Sigma' = \O_K \setminus \p$ for a single fixed prime $\p$ of $\O_K$, you also get that $(\Sigma')^{-1}\O_K = (\O_K)_{\p}$ is a PID : it is even a DVR.

This is a result similar to the claim above, but which is in fact quite unrelated, since $\Sigma$ deals with the *co*finite set $\mathrm{Spec}(\O_K) \setminus S$ of primes, while $\Sigma'$ deals with the *finite* set $\{\p\}$...

Comment: Further reference: proposition 5.3.6 in _Heights in Diophantine Geometry_.